# Uncheck a checkbox and another checkbox will untick

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have two checkboxes in a form. onclick if a checkbox called email is unchecked how can I get the other checkbox to also uncheck (if it is checked) ?

```
document.getElementById('email').onclick = function() {
     if (!this.checked) {
        !document.getElementById("other").checked;
    } else {
        // if not checked ...
    }
};
```

Am I completey barking up the wrong tree? Any help appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like :

```
<form id="test" action="#" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"/>
    </div>

        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {

```
 if (!this.checked) {
    document.getElementById("check2").checked = false;
} else {

    // other logic ...
}};
```

Test it online on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3dtq0w8x/

Answer (score 3):

To synchronize the checking of the both at the same time you need just to use `this.checked` of the first clicked one on the `checked` attribute of the second one like :

```
document.getElementById("other").checked = this.checked;
```

**NOTE :** That will work on one way, what means the check will be synchronized just when you click on the first `checkbox` that you've attached the click event to.

```js
document.getElementById('email').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("other").checked = this.checked;
};
```

```html
<input id="email" type="checkbox" /> CHECKBOX 1
<br>
<input id="other" type="checkbox" /> CHECKBOX 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test code you are not setting the *checked*  property of "other" to any value.
You are just reading its value, then inverting it (with !).

You could try:

```
document.getElementById("other").checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener to `email` checkbox (which is a good practice) and then check if it is check or not and deal with the other checkbox according to that

For example

```js
var ckb = document.getElementById('email')
ckb.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(!e.target.checked)
      document.getElementById('ot').checked = false;
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="na" value="email" id="email">Email<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="na" value="other" id="ot">Other
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
function check() {
if(document.getElementById("email").checked){ 
    document.getElementById("other").checked = true;
}else{
    document.getElementById("other").checked = false;
}
```

}

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' id='email' name='checkbox' onclick="check()" >email
<input type='checkbox' id='other' name='checkbox'>other
```